# I want to store pointOfView.position of allowsCameraControl in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, scenekit

I have a SenceKit SceneView with lights camera and a model. I also have `view.allowsCameraControl = YES`.

I realize that when I use this it creates a new camera attached to the `rootNode` of my scene. I'm trying to capture the position, rotation, and orientation of the camera and store it in core-data. So when the project is called again, those values can be put into my camera that I put in the scene.

Right now I have an app that creates a project with a static camera set to `SCNVectorMake3(0, -550, 900)` That's were the camera starts when the user gestures in the view they can pinch, pan and rotate and when they click save in renders the scene and saves all there other edits like text and background image in core-data but of course, I have to add an attribute to an Entity for thous values.

I have added an `NSLog` to print out the position, rotation and orientation in the output window, so I know the data is generated and should be retrievable. I need a variable for camera position, rotation and orientation and a method that that checks to make sure they are not `(0, 0, 0)` and if they are set them to a default of `(0, -550, 900)`.

I apologise for my lack of experience but I'm just learning Objective-c. I've been all over the internet and seen a few methods of arc ball rotation but nothing that grabs values out of SecneKits `allowsCameraControl` function and adds them to the camera which would in my case be an easy solution.

Here is my code...

```
- (struct SCNVector3) readCameraPosition {


    return SCNVector3Make(
            _topScene.pointOfView.position.x,
            _topScene.pointOfView.position.y,
            _topScene.pointOfView.position.z);

    }



- (void) update3DTextForScene: (SCNView *)view{
    height3DString = 0;

    view.scene = [SCNScene scene];

    view.allowsCameraControl = YES;

    SCNScene *scene = view.scene;



NSLog(@"Camera position: %f %f %f",
      _topScene.pointOfView.position.x,
      _topScene.pointOfView.position.y,
      _topScene.pointOfView.position.z);

NSLog(@"Camera rotation: %f %f %f %f",
      _topScene.pointOfView.rotation.x,
      _topScene.pointOfView.rotation.y,
      _topScene.pointOfView.rotation.z,
      _topScene.pointOfView.rotation.w);

NSLog(@"Camera orientat: %f %f %f %f",
      _topScene.pointOfView.orientation.x,
      _topScene.pointOfView.orientation.y,
      _topScene.pointOfView.orientation.z,
      _topScene.pointOfView.orientation.w);




view.backgroundColor = [UIColor UIColorFromRGBAhex:0xFFFFFF00];

// camera
self.cameraNode = [SCNNode node];
self.cameraNode.camera = [SCNCamera camera];
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:self.cameraNode];
view.pointOfView = self.cameraNode;

self.cameraNode.camera.zFar = 10000;
self.cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -550, 900);
self.cameraNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(1.0, 0, 0, 0.588002);
self.cameraNode.orientation = SCNVector4Make(0.289784, 0, 0, 0.957092);
self.cameraNode.camera.xFov = 40;
//self.cameraNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(atan(2./3.), 0, 0);


// light
UIColor *lightColorLeft = [UIColor UIColorFromRGBhex:0xFFFFFF];
UIColor *lightColorRight = [UIColor UIColorFromRGBhex:0xFFFFFF];

_lightLeftNode = [SCNNode node];
_lightLeftNode.light = [SCNLight light];
_lightLeftNode.light.type = SCNLightTypeSpot;
_lightLeftNode.light.color = lightColorLeft;
_lightLeftNode.light.spotInnerAngle = 30;
_lightLeftNode.light.spotOuterAngle = 120;
_lightLeftNode.light.shadowRadius = 5.0;
_lightLeftNode.light.zFar = 10000;
_lightLeftNode.castsShadow = YES;
_lightLeftNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0.6, 0, 0);
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:_lightLeftNode];

_lightRightNode = [SCNNode node];
_lightRightNode.light = [SCNLight light];
_lightRightNode.light.type = SCNLightTypeSpot;
_lightRightNode.light.color = lightColorRight;
_lightRightNode.light.spotInnerAngle = 30;
_lightRightNode.light.spotOuterAngle = 120;
_lightRightNode.light.shadowRadius = 5.0;
_lightRightNode.light.zFar = 10000;
_lightRightNode.castsShadow = YES;
_lightRightNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0.6, 0, 0);
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:_lightRightNode];

// text
_arrayTextNodes = [NSMutableArray new];

NSString *text = [_project findBlockWithType:0].text;
NSArray *stringArray = [text componentsSeparatedByString: @"\n"];
for (NSString  *string in stringArray) {
    [_arrayTextNodes addObject: [self addTextNoteWithText: string view:view]];
}

CGFloat height = 0;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < _arrayTextNodes.count; ++i) {
    height += [self takeANewPositionForTextNote: _arrayTextNodes[i] withIndex:     i];
}

self.lightRightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(300,
                                              250,
                                              600);
self.lightLeftNode.position = SCNVector3Make(-300,
                                             250,
                                             600);
self.lightRightNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0.2, 0.1, 0);
self.lightLeftNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(0.2, -0.1, 0);



}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark - ScreenKit
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (SCNNode *) addTextNoteWithText: (NSString *) text view:(SCNView *)view{
TextBlock *textBlockTopScene = [_project findBlockWithType:0];

CGFloat mainSize = textBlockTopScene? [textBlockTopScene.size integerValue] * 3 : 90;
SCNText *sceneText = [SCNText textWithString:text extrusionDepth:   textBlockTopScene? [textBlockTopScene.depth doubleValue] : mainSize / 3. ];



sceneText.chamferRadius = MIN(sceneText.extrusionDepth / 5., 5); // first way


sceneText.font = textBlockTopScene?
    [UIFont fontWithName:textBlockTopScene.font size: mainSize] :
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size: mainSize];
sceneText.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
sceneText.wrapped = YES;

SCNNode *textNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry:sceneText];

SCNMaterial *material1 = [SCNMaterial new];
material1.diffuse.contents = [UIColor UIColorFromRGBhex: textBlockTopScene?   [textBlockTopScene.color integerValue] : 0];
UIColor * specularColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage   imageNamed:@"noise"]];
material1.specular.contents = [specularColor offsetWithHue:0 saturation:0   lightness: textBlockTopScene? [textBlockTopScene.specular doubleValue] : 0.5   alpha:0];

textNode.geometry.materials = @[material1];
[view.scene.rootNode addChildNode:textNode];

return textNode;
}

- (CGFloat) takeANewPositionForTextNote: (SCNNode *) textNode withIndex:    (NSInteger) index{
SCNVector3 v1 = SCNVector3Make(0,0,0);
SCNVector3 v2 = SCNVector3Make(0,0,0);
[textNode getBoundingBoxMin:&v1 max:&v2];

NSInteger count = _arrayTextNodes.count;

CGFloat dx = (v1.x - v2.x) / 2.0;
CGFloat dy = (v1.y - v2.y) / 2.0;

if (!height3DString) {
    height3DString = dy;
}

textNode.position = SCNVector3Make(dx,
                                   height3DString * ((count + index * 2.5) -    (count - 1) * 2.5),
                                   0);

return dy * 1.25;
}
```

But when you run the app you'er either creating a new project that has default setting for camera position or opening a project that has already been saved in core data with edits made to it. If I don't save the users changes to the camera position in core-data when they close the project they will be lost and set to the defaults when they re-open it. Does that make sense why I need to use core-data?

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is designed to store a significant amount of complex data.  If you are looking to ONLY store three floats then I would suggest using something less complicated and easier for you to work with.  Perhaps using `NSUserDefaults`.

If you are storing more data then I would suggest creating a `Camera` entity that has three float values.  Then store each float in the correct property.  There is no reason to store a complex data structure inside of Core Data.  Core Data is already a complex data structure.

Just store the primitive values.

> But when you run the app you'er either creating a new project that has default setting or opening a project that has already had edits made to it, thous edits are stored in core data because when you create a new project or start to edit another one all the data that is not stored in core-data gets released, thrown out. If the user moves the camera then saves and then opens the saved project I need the camera to be in the last saved position and rotation. Does that make sense why I need to use core-data?

No it doesn't but that is fine.  I do need to understand your persistence choice.  If you are storing more than just the Camera position then great, use Core Data.

If you are storing just **ONE** reference to **ONE** camera *ever* then Core Data is overkill.  That was my point.

Nevertheless, you don't need to store a complex object, the answer to your original question is store the three float values and then you can re-set them into the Camera object on the next launch.

Comment: But when you run the app you'er either creating a new project that has default setting or opening a project that has already had edits made to it, thous edits are stored in core data because when you create a new project or start to edit another one all the data that is not stored in core-data gets released, thrown out. If the user moves the camera then saves and then opens the saved project I need the camera to be in the last saved position and rotation. Does that make sense why I need to use core-data?

Comment: Fist of all thanks for your help Marcus I really appreciate it. I don't know if I'm explaining it right or I just don't understand your answer. I'm already using CoreData. I store three entities Project, BackgroundSettings, TextBlock. Under Project I have five Attributes, backgroundURL, dateCreated, imageURL, name and orientation. I thought I would add one right now just for cameraPosition if I could get that to work I would add two more cameraRotation and cameraOrientation.

Comment: In the app you can create a new project, when you do that it creates all the settings at default. You then set about changing the background image, the text, the font used, the size of the text and other user defined choices, then you save. All thous edits are now saved in core-data. There is a list view with all your projects it could be zero to fifty different projects. How do I get the changed camera position in each project to save with that project if I don't use CoreData? These are cards people are making and saving and the returning to to make edits. Thanks again for your help.